# Select data from database where date in current month

Tags: c#, sql, linq, datagridview, entity-framework-core

I have a button to show me my note's from my database in this month but there is a problem, when I used this LINQ, I got this error

> System.InvalidOperationException
> The LINQ expression 'DbSet()
> .Where(r => r.Date == (Nullable)Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.Now.Month))' could not
> be translated.

When I don't convert `DateTime.Now.Month` to datetime, I got this error too for my below code:

> Operator'==' can't be applied to operands of type 'DateTime?' and 'int'

Code:

```
var z = mydb.ReminderTbls
            .Where(x => x.Date == DateTime.Now.Month);
```

This is my full code:

```
var z = mydb.ReminderTbls
            .Where(x => x.Date == Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.Now.Month));

noteDataGridView.Rows.Clear();

foreach (var item in z)
{
    noteDataGridView.Rows.Add(item.Id, item.Desciption, String.Format("{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", item.Date.Value.GetPdate()));
}
```

Comment: DateTime.Now.Month is an `int` which cannot be converted to a Date. You need to query for dates between the 1st and last day of the month, or where the month and year equal the month and year you want.

Comment: `var startOfMonth = new DateTime(now.Year, now.Month, 1);
            var endOfMonth = new DateTime(now.Year, now.Month, 31);
            var z = mydb.ReminderTbls.Where(x => x.Date >= startOfMonth && x.Date <= endOfMonth);`

that query is working thank you

Comment: That only works for months with 31 days. Use [DaysInMonth](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.daysinmonth?view=net-6.0) to make it dynamic and account for leap years.

Answer (score 2):

You can use begin of month and make comparison which is preferred by databases and uses indexes, if they exist for sure:

```cs
var startDate = DateTime.Now.Date;
startDate = new DateTime(startDate.Year, startDate.Month, 1);

var endDate = startDate.AddMonths(1);

var z = mydb.ReminderTbls.Where(x => x.Date >= startDate && x.Date < endDate);
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to compare months is to take the year,month and scale it so that we have an integer of the format YYYYMM and then a simple arithmetic comparison will work. However for IQueryables this may not work, and for IEnumerables with large datasets this can be slow and using a simple date range or DbFunctions as explained next is a better approach.

e.g.

```
{
    int count = 100;
    var sd = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-count);
    var vals = Enumerable.Range(0,count).Select(xx=> new {Date = sd.AddDays(xx)});
    var refdate = DateTime.Now;
    var thisMonth = vals.Where(xx=> (xx.Date.Year*100 + xx.Date.Month) == (refdate.Date.Year*100 + refdate.Date.Month));
}
```

With EntityFramework there are also functions that are available that will do this in the database (when using an IQueryable). This has the disadvantage that probably the underlying DBMS will not be able to use indexes.

```
var referenceDate = DateTime.Now;
ReminderTbls.AsQueryable().Where(x => x.Date.HasValue && DbFunctions.DiffMonths(x.Date.Value, referenceDate) == 0);
```

Thanks to @Gert Arnold for commenting that @Svyatoslav Danyliv's answer is sargable[2] as it uses a date range comparison which is a better solution because it will benefit from any indexes on the server so I would recommend @Svyatoslav Danyliv's approach, i.e.

```
var startDate = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Date.Year, DateTime.Now.Date.Month,1);
var endDate = startDate.AddMonths(1);
ReminderTbls.Where(xx => xx.Date.HasValue && xx.Date >= startDate && xx.Date < endDate);
```

---

[1] As a separate issue all dates in database should be stored in UTC.

[2] sargable is when the DBMS engine can take advantage of an index to speed up the execution of the query (Search ARGument ABLE).

Comment: If it translates the main drawback remains: it's not sargable. A range check (Svyatoslav's answer) is.